# How to know which foreign key constraint failed in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

The problem is simple enough. When a foreign key constraint fails in SQLite I do not know how to determine which failed.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP.child;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP.parent;

CREATE TEMP TABLE parent (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE child (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    parent_id2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT no_a CHECK (name IS NOT 'a'),
    CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id1) REFERENCES parent (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id2) REFERENCES parent (id)
);
```

Below each of the queries I will paste the error/result. You'll see that for the named constraint `no_a` that it shows in the error, but not for the foreign keys.

```
INSERT INTO TEMP.child VALUES (1, 0, 0, 'a');
-- [19:43:32] Error while executing SQL query on database 'petstore': CHECK constraint failed: no_a

INSERT INTO TEMP.child VALUES (1, 0, 0, 'b');
-- [19:44:28] Error while executing SQL query on database 'petstore': FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

INSERT INTO TEMP.parent VALUES (1);
-- [19:44:50] Query finished in 0.000 second(s). Rows affected: 1

INSERT INTO TEMP.child VALUES (1, 1, 0, 'b');
-- [19:46:03] Error while executing SQL query on database 'petstore': FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

INSERT INTO TEMP.child VALUES (1, 0, 1, 'b');
-- [19:46:11] Error while executing SQL query on database 'petstore': FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

INSERT INTO TEMP.child VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'b');
-- [19:46:18] Query finished in 0.001 second(s). Rows affected: 1
```

Comment: Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy I did google the error, it was nothing but people asking what this error meant, not how to make it more specific. (As in people not knowing what foreign keys were and wondering how to "fix" it.) Also, skimming the "how to ask" it looks like I met all the criteria, what specifically did I do wrong? You say to use one certain phrasing as the title, I don't know how to make it more specific than "How to know which foreign key constraint failed in SQLite?"

Comment: I've updated the title of the other question so hopefully it sticks out more for future people having this problem.

Comment: I left that comment because research is expected & duplicates are discouraged & reason to close. My comment is a generic one & I left it because this could clearly be expected to be a duplicate & is & all I had to do was google your title. Being generic, my comment's mention of various things is just meant to cover most things people would be asking about & should do. I wasn't referring to your FK error, I was addressing "your question", how to pin down such an error. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se] See also the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: @philipxy Not sure how I need to show research effort other than saying "I researched." I searched here as well as Google for quite some time and didn't find that question which the other user (you? The comment is gone now, don't remember who it was from) mentioned that this duplicated (nor any other answer). I also checked SQLite's docs but I can't just copy the entire page and say that it doesn't say. Regardless, as I mentioned, I hope now that these two questions having better titles makes them stick out above everyone who just doesn't under FKs at all and want this answered specifically.

Comment: Just give a reasonable summary of how/what you researched so people will know. "I researched" doesn't. It doesn't even mean anything, nor does not mentioning research, because people have different ideas of what is reasonable research or may not know they should research & if askers don't say then readers don't know. Eg you should have read every reference to FK constraints & errors in the manual. So say that you did, or if you didn't people can say, do so. If you only used SE search, summarize the main things you searched for, and we can say, google, SE search is not helpful. Etc etc.